# Client part of the Digest Authentication using PHP POST to Web Service

Tags: php, digest-authentication

I'm trying to POST to a Web Service (not RESTful) and get response through PHP. However, that web service requires Digest Authentication.

I've been searching online and found most of the discussions and articles are about the other way around (Requesting Digest Authentications to users), instead of responding it, using PHP.

I'm able to generate the Digest response using the code this thread provide:[HTTP Digest authenticating in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975307/http-digest-authenticating-in-php), but the problem is to sending it along with(or not?) the POST data.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$domain = "https://api.example.com";
$uri = "/ws.asmx/do";

// get headers
$response1_array = get_headers($web_service_url);
// get request part of digest auth
$response1 = $response1_array[5];
// get things behind "WWW-Authenticate:"
$response1 = substr($response1, 18);

// response() is a invented function to calculate the response according to the RFC2617
$response2 = response($response1, "username", "password", "GET", $uri);

// manually add some headers for POST, and fill out the parts that the calculation function missed
// for auth
$header =  
        "Host: api.example.com\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
        "Authorization: " . $response2 . ", nc=\"00000001\", opaque=\"0000000000000000\"" . "\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";

// echo the response from server
echo do_post_request($web_service_url, "", $header);

function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

  $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);

  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url");
  }
  $response = stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

In the response:

```
$response1(from web service):
    Digest realm="example.com", nonce="OS82LzIwMTMgMTI6MDI6NDYgUE0", opaque="0000000000000000", stale=false, algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"

$response2(I calculated given the server response):
    Digest username="username", realm="example.com", nonce="OS82LzIwMTMgMTI6MDI6NDYgUE0", uri="/ws.asmx/do", cnonce="1378494106", nc="1", response="0f96788854cf2098ba22c6121529d7de", qop="auth"

the final (2nd) response from server:
    Warning: fopen(https://api.example.com/ws.asmx/do): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in ...
```

I don't understand why server responded 500 error in this case. Is there anything wrong in the code? Or has anyone met this problem before and solved it and can help me with a solution?

Regards,

Mylo

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Eventually solved it with cURL after 2 days' fumbling. I guess this is the first time a piece of ready-made PHP code for digest auth is posted, hopefully it can help someone who are in the same ditch as I was in.

Code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

$url = "https://api.example.com/ws.asmx/do";
$username = "username";
$password = "pwd";
$post_data = array(
        'fieldname1' => 'value1',
        'fieldname2' => 'value2'
  );

$options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // for https
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ":" . $password,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post_data) 
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

try {
  $raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );

  // validate CURL status
  if(curl_errno($ch))
      throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), 500);

  // validate HTTP status code (user/password credential issues)
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if ($status_code != 200)
      throw new Exception("Response with Status Code [" . $status_code . "].", 500);

} catch(Exception $ex) {
    if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
    throw new Exception($ex);
}

if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);

echo "raw response: " . $raw_response; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send JSON data with PUT method:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

$url = "https://api.example.com/ws.asmx/do";
$username = "username";
$password = "pwd";
$post_data = array(
        'fieldname1' => 'value1',
        'fieldname2' => 'value2'
  );

$options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // for https
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ":" . $password,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "PUT",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($post_data) ,
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

try {
  $raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );

  // validate CURL status
  if(curl_errno($ch))
      throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), 500);

  // validate HTTP status code (user/password credential issues)
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if ($status_code != 200)
      throw new Exception("Response with Status Code [" . $status_code . "].", 500);

} catch(Exception $ex) {
    if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
    throw new Exception($ex);
}

if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);

echo "raw response: " . $raw_response; 

?>
```